# Input type="file" take a photo option

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, modernizr

I'm wondering why camera/select-file behavior differs not only between browsers (Chrome, Safari), but also between the same browser on different platforms (Android Chrome vs iPhone Chrome)?

`Modernizr.getusermedia` returns `true` for Chrome on Android, but `false` for Chrome on iPhone.

**Problem:** on iPhone `Modernizr.getusermedia === false`, but on `<input type="file" />` menu Chrome/Safari propose me to make a photo/video.

**Question:** *is there any way to take under JavaScript control that behaviour?*

Comment: Just as an aside - chrome on android is in _no_ way the same browser as chrome on ios. at all. Apple does not allow for third party web engines. As a result, chrome on ios is just a wrapper around safari's web view.

Comment: @Patrick thanks, good point

Answer (score 7):

Tried adding `capture` attribute to `input` element ?

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

See [Polyfill file input with accept capture (using getUserMedia to capture?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626925/polyfill-file-input-with-accept-capture-using-getusermedia-to-capture) , [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: nice suggestion, will try it today!

Comment: `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` was replaced with `accept="image/*" capture` in the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html-media-capture-20130509/). Use `capture="capture"`  only if you want to capture directly from the camera. See [Correct Syntax for HTML Media Capture](https://addpipe.com/blog/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for more details.

Comment: @OctavianNaicu See also https://www.w3.org/2009/dap/wiki/ImplementationStatus ,  http://w3c.github.io/test-results/html-media-capture/all.html

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering why camera/select-file behavior differs between the same browser on different platforms (Android Chrome vs iPhone Chrome)?

[Chrome on iOS is actually just a wrapper around Webkit](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/01/new-chrome-for-ios-is-finally-as-fast-and-stable-as-safari/), Safari's rendering engine.

> on iPhone `Modernizr.getusermedia === false`, but on `<input type="file" />` menu Chrome/Safari propose me to make a photo/video.

Those are two different APIs. [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) is a complex JavaScript API not implemented by Safari, while [`<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523544/html-file-input-control-with-capture-and-accept-attributes-works-wrong) is a very simple HTML5 API.