# How to only allow take picture on Mobile View Port for input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Website. There's a step needed users to upload images. May I ask how to prevent users from uploading images, only allow to take picture and upload on Mobile View?

Comment: You might be looking for this: <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">

Comment: HTML5Rocks did a post on this: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: vow, many thanks bro. I will try these out

Comment: Or this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351456/input-type-file-take-a-photo-option

Comment: simple as this: <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>